# Notation $X/Y$ in Vickers 'Topology via Logic

Tags: general-topology, logic

I am currently working through Vickers' book 'Topology via Logic'.
At one point (Proof of Theorem 4.4.2) he uses the notation $X/Y = \{z\in S \mid \forall y\in Y: y\wedge z\in X\}$ (and $X\wedge Y = \{x\wedge y\mid x\in X, y\in Y\}$), $X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary subsets in $S$.
My question is how I can imagine $X/Y$ to look like.

For the context:
$\underline{\textrm{cover relation}}$ in $S$: a formula $U\dashv a$ ($U$ covers $a$), with $a\in S$, $U$ in the lower closure of $a$ ($\{y\in S| y\leq a\}$). This means $\bigvee U = a$

$\underline{\textrm{coverage}}$ on $S$ is a set $C$ of cover relations such that for $U\dashv a$ in $C$ and $b\leq a$ holds: if $\bigvee U = a$, then $\bigvee\{b\wedge u| u\in U\} = b\wedge a = b$.

$\underline{C\textrm{-ideal}}$: $C$ a coverage on $S$, a $C$-ideal is a subset $I$ satisfying:
-$I$ is lower closed
-If $U\dashv a$ a cover reation in $C$ and $U\subseteq I$, then $a\in I$.

Theorem 4.4.2: Let $S$ be a semilattice, $C'$ a set of cover relations and $C$ the coverage it generates.
(i) a $C$-ideal is a frame under the subset ordering ($I\leq J$ iff $I\subseteq J$).

Now for the proof of (i) in the part to prove the distributivity he introduces this notion.
In a later proposition he states:
$Z\subseteq X/Y \Leftrightarrow Y\wedge Z\subseteq X\Leftrightarrow Y\subseteq X/Z$

Comment: As of now, your question can only be answered by somebody looking at the book, because it is not self-contained. I was able to determine via the tiny snippet available via Google Books that $S$ is a (meet) semilattice. But I don't recall what a "cut" is in that context.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I'll change the question.

Comment: My question to all of this is how I can understand the definition of $X/Y$ because to me it seems that it is just the cut of $X$ and $Y$ in $S$?